# show image from my web server to my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, image, download

i have soome image (.jpg,.png etc) stored in my web server.
i am building an iPhone application which can upload or download images from/to my webserver.

i can upload images to my web server.

but i can not download images from my web server to my application.
How i can do it????

Comment: hi faisal, can u help me how to upload image to the server from iphone

thanks

Comment: but how?
where will i write the code snipt?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest technique by using UIKit

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://images.com/image.jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Image From URL

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {
    UIImage * result;

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return result;
}
```

Save Image

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        ALog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}
```

Load Image

```
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]];

    return result;
}
```

How-To

```
//Definitions
NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

//Get Image From URL
UIImage * imageFromURL = [self getImageFromURL:@"http://www.yourdomain.com/yourImage.png"];

//Save Image to Directory
[self saveImage:imageFromURL withFileName:@"My Image" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];

//Load Image From Directory
UIImage * imageFromWeb = [self loadImage:@"My Image" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];
```

For more details see these links

[iOS: Download image from url and save in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499176/ios-download-image-from-url-and-save-in-device)

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/download-and-create-an-image-from-a-url.html