# Why does my image fail to write to file and display?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to both download, save, and display an image.

I am using this code, which DOES work when I directly load *image.

```
 [self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        // Set the image
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];

        // Save image.
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        UIImage * imag2e = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Image"];
        weakSelf.imageView.image = imag2e;

        [self updateZoom];
        [self updateConstraints];

        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:weakSelf.view animated:YES];
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"An error occured when loading the image, %@", [error description]);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:weakSelf.view animated:YES];
    }];
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Writing? Loading? Showing Image? Is your block in background? If that's the case, you can only update UI in main thread.

Comment: It seems that you are using AFNeworking is possible that second time your image is loaded from the cache and I don't remember if the success block is called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499176/ios-download-image-from-url-and-save-in-device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is on the line:

```
UIImage * imag2e = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Image"];
```

In the documentation for [+[UIImage imageNamed:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) it states:

> If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the **application’s main bundle.**

And the saved image is located elsewhere. E.g. try:

```
UIImage * imag2e = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
```

Comment: Yep, this guy nails it.