# Ios swift - storing uiimage in document directory and path in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm currently storing my images directly in core data and experiencing issues when having to retrieve a high quality images.

I was advised to store the images in the document directory and save a path in core-data as to not store the actual images there but simply the address of where I can go and find it.

Can someone push me in the right direction? Can't seem to find the appropriate guidance?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499176/ios-download-image-from-url-and-save-in-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answers to all my questions in this youtube video -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vk4UrJR8WM

This is the github with the file that has instructions as to how to complete this - https://github.com/TDAbboud/WeightLogger-Images

Comment: you should write the answer instead of posting links, in case those links were broken some day

Answer (score 0):

Try Hanake cache: https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke
It worked really well for me personally with the same problem. It makes a sometimes painful task pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Save an image in Document directory is easy this code is not optimized is just for give you a hint( you should manage errors, optionals etc). Suppose that you already have a valid `UIImage` instance called `image` and a valid image name `String` called `imageName`

```
                let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                // Unwrapping the data optional
                if let data = data {
                    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
                    let path = (paths.first! as! NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
                    data.writeToFile(path, options: [])
                  //Save the path into your managed object
                    }
```