# Download Image from Api Url and show in Collection view in swift using Alamofire

Tags: swift

I already am able to fetch the url from the Api which is in Json format. But this one is the image url. now how can I able to download that image from url and show in collection view.  I have

**code**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://\(platform).eposapi.co.uk/?app_id=\(apiID)&app_key=\(apikey)&request=&request=gallery", parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                   self.imageData = JSON as! Array<AnyObject>
                   print(self.imageData)
                   print("total number of images = \(self.imageData.count)")
                   for image in self.imageData{
                   print(image)
            }



    }
```

In `JSON` all the image url are coming . I can see it. Now how to download image from that url and show in collection view. Please tell anyone how can I apply here.

The image url I got is:

> [http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14517241531454.jpg,
>         http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14517241944082.jpg, 
>         http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14517273984235.jpg, 
>        http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14517274885779.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/1451727556453.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14614027267627.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14517278515475.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14614068518289.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14616123258824.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14614027528137.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14517344227700.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/1461402768681.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14614028323203.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14614029485351.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14614029565341.jpg, http://chicoshorwich.com/img/14614068296679.jpg]
>   total number of images = 16

Please tell the solution.

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499176/ios-download-image-from-url-and-save-in-device

Comment: Can you able to send in swift @SubinKKuriakose

Comment: It is lot easier with Alamofire. cant you use Alamofire in you project? If you can its really really easy.

Comment: ok then send a link  using Alamofire  to resolve this.@Ccr

Comment: I have edited the codes with alamofire . now can you please give idea how to download images from the coming url @Ccr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my code . this is I think exact your answer according to your data. I have edited few things  in your codes.Try it.

**code**

```
         Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://\(platform).eposapi.co.uk/?app_id=\
        (apiID)&app_key=\(apikey)&request=&request=gallery", parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
                       print(response.request)  // original URL request
                       print(response.response) // URL response
                       // print(response.data)     // server data
                       print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                        self.imageData = JSON as! Array<String>
                        print(self.imageData)
                        print("total number of images = \(self.imageData.count)\n")
                        for image in self.imageData{
                        print(image)
                    }
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.GalleryCollectionView.reloadData()
                        }


                 }
```

now create a custom Collectionviewcell named "GalleryCollectionViewCell" and add it to the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Gallerycell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GalleryCollectionViewCell


    let url = NSURL(string: imageData[indexPath.row])
    cell.galleryImageView.af_setImageWithURL(url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "logo.png"), filter: nil,  imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: nil)


return cell
}
```

On "placeholder"  take any loader image from assets. I have used here logo.png. You can take yours.

Comment: o yeah thanks It works. Actually the problem is during the reload(). I have not added it thats why  the countdown of imageData  remains Zero and nothing happened.

Comment: Hello @PRADIPKUMAR

Comment: @PoojaSrivastava  // declare  self.imageData as  Array<String> on top and then use it...whats your response data.. show me your response data.. or better post a question with you  code that you have added and then  ping me ..

Comment: response =     {
        code = 200;
        radioList =         (
                        {
                "genre_name" =                 (
                                        {
                        "genre_id" = 1;
                        "genre_name" = Country;
                    }
                );
                "radio_des" = "Lee Brice - Love Like Crazy ";
                "radio_img" = "https://dousic.com/uploads/s48937q.png";
}

Comment: let components=URLComponents(url:url,resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
        let params = ["user_id":"16"]
  Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {response in
            var err:Error?
            switch response.result {case .success(let value):
                 let json = JSON(value)
                  if let resData = json["response"]["radioList"].array {
                    self.array_RadioList = resData
                    self.tbl_home.reloadData()}
        case .failure(let error):
                err = error}}}

Comment: let url = URL(string: "https://dousic.com/api/radiolist")! @PRADIP KUMAR

Comment: @PoojaSrivastava in you code where you are fetching "radio_img". Create a separate array of string only for saving all the images in one and then add the  above codes. This one may be helpful .. https://paste.ubuntu.com/25712092/

Comment: for item in  self.array_RadioList!{
                    
                    let myRadioListArray =  item as! NSDictionary
                    let radioImg = myRadioListArray.value(forkey:"radio_img" )as! String
                    self.imageData.append(radioImg)
                    
                }

Comment: let radioImg = myRadioListArray.value(forkey:"radio_img" )as! String Argument labels '(forkey:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: this is my full url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156340/discussion-between-pradip-kumar-and-pooja-srivastava).

Answer (score 0):

You can call all images URL one by one

```
//define your dispatch queue

    private let downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("ru.downloadimage.downloadQueue", nil)

//Define also this
private var photos = [NSURL]()

// Add your URL here like this or you can do as per your choice
if let urls = jsonDictionary.valueForKeyPath("download data") as? [String] {
                for (i, url) in urls.enumerate() {
                    photos.append(NSURL(string: url)!)
                }
            }
```

This is code for Download block for images here

```
// Define the cache variable first 
private var cache = NSCache()



// MARK: - Private

    private func downloadPhoto(url: NSURL, completion: (url: NSURL, image: UIImage) -> Void) {
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, { () -> Void in
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.cache.setObject(image, forKey: url)
                        completion(url: url, image: image)
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Call this function from Collection View like this

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
        let url = photos[indexPath.item]
        let image = cache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage

        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        cell.imageView.image = image

        if image == nil {
            downloadPhoto(url, completion: { (url, image) -> Void in
                let indexPath_ = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
                if indexPath.isEqual(indexPath_) {
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                }
            })
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: In your code what type of item and downloadQueue  no such description here @Anand

Comment: Please elaborate then only I can able to apply it in my code

Comment: I can not write here full i am here giving you hint try to make easier and i make changes on code so you can easily understand. "item" was there your json data dictionary , getting image array and put inside the NSURL array there and this code easy to apply and easy to understand.

Comment: If you having any issue again let me know i will try to solve your problem.

Comment: I am here giving way. how to do this thing exact work depend on you and how you understand this code.

Comment: One more thing in url call one by on what is  "download data" and  "ru.downloadimage.downloadQueue"

Comment: Please try to understand here you need to pass url inside that block and you can do your own way make url array from your json data. i just put there as a example.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to download image with Alamofire if you have imageURL.

make sure you have import `AlamofireImage` pod installed and you have

```
import AlamofireImage

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url) // url is string here.
                .responseImage { response in 
                    if let image = response.result.value {
                        // image is here. 
                    }else{
                        // check what happned.
                    }
            }
```

more information can be found @ https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Comment: thats good but here instead of url as string i have array of objects .. so how can i take each image url one by one to fetch it. see my above edited codes please

Comment: write above code inside  cellForItemAtIndexPath and provide url from url array. Ccr code is correct.But some cases the above code is take time to update UI .So instead of above use the below code if you  are using AlamofireImage.            yourCell.yourCell_ImageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: imageUrl)!)

Answer (score 0):

write The Ccr code inside  cellForItemAtIndexPath and provide url from url array. Ccr code is correct.But some cases the above code takes time to update UI .So instead of above use the below code if you  are using AlamofireImage.

```
 yourCell.yourCell_ImageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: imageUrl)!)
```