# Storing custom images in iPad application for use in App

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am making an iPad application (iOS 5.0/5.1 with ARC and storyboard) for which I need to download an image or sound file from my server and then use it as background for all the screens of my application. I was thinking of keeping a placeholder image/audio file bundled within my application which I will refer to within the storyboard. Then when I get the file from the server, I can replace that image with the one coming from the server. However, I'm not sure if this can be done based on the directories that the app has access to.

Pls let me know if you can direct me whether it's possible to go down this road? and if yes, then which directory should I be downloading the image files to?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You can find a good tutorial on doing this in the accepted answer linked in this post. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app) and as a bonus heres the Apple sample code for site reachability, so not only can you specify for the app to only attempt to try to download images if a network connection is established, but you can also define different image sizes (or what ever you want) based on wether the phone is connected with wifi or cellular. [https://developer.apple.c

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286096/getting-image-from-url-server, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499176/ios-download-image-from-url-and-save-in-device and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587596/show-image-from-my-web-server-to-my-iphone-application